# Spring Boot and GCP: No qualifying bean of type org.springframework.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.SecretManagerTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-gcp, google-secret-manager

Getting error while connecting to GCP to get the secret from the secret manager, but somehow it's not working for me.

Getting error while running the application as:

**No qualifying bean of type org.springframework.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.SecretManagerTemplate**

I am using SecretManagerTemplate as below to fetch the secret:

```
secretManagerTemplate.getSecretString(keyName);
```

Details:

- Spring Boot version: 2.1.8
- Spring Cloud version: Greenwich.RELEASE
- Spring Cloud GCP version 1.2.5.RELEASE

**Note:** I don't want to upgrade the Spring Boot version.

Please help.

Comment: Did you follow all the [steps](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/#secret-manager) required for the component configuration? Basically you need to define the right project dependencies: ```<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>```. Does the console print any error?

Comment: Thanks, @jccampanero for the comment, and yes I have added all required dependencies mentioned in the steps. And the error I am getting is the same as No qualifying bean of type for this SecretManagerTemplate in case of Autowired.

Comment: And just to update, if I upgrade to version like 2.3.1 or later it is working fine, but with the latest version we do have some Spring Boot memory issues so we cannot upgrade our application.